# API call works on Postman but doesn't work on my code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, postman, fetch-api

I have to update some user info, it works fine on postman but when I try to type it in react-native I must be doing something wrong in the body of the fetch method. In postman I set x-www-form-urlencoded and type the keys like this:

Key        -----                          Value

moto            -----                    test

and that seems to work, but when I try to do the same on my code I somehow fail at it. Here is my code:

```
updateUser(){

 return fetch(url,{
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token": bearerToken,
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                  moto: this.state.moto
          }
    })
  }
)
```

I get 200 response which means the call works but I must be seting the parameter moto wrong somehow.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

> "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

should be

"Content-Type":"application/json"

Answer (score 0):

`form-urlencoded` is way different from your `body: JSON.stringify()`.

You'll want to use a `FormData` object instead:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('moto', this.state.moto);
fetch(url, {
  method: "PATCH",
  headers: {
    "X-Auth-Token": bearerToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  body,
})
```

Comment: I tryed your code but still nothing .The call gets done but the parameter must be typed wrong.I ll post you the console.log(body) and maybe you can figure this out. FormData[_parts: Array(1)}=> parts : Array(1)  => 0:"moto" 1:test

Answer (score 0):

```
APICall = () => { 
  fetch(‘Your http URL’, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    ‘X-Auth-Token’: bearerToken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      moto: this.state.moto
    }) 
  }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {      
    if(responseJson.statuscode == 1) {
      Alert.alert('Success');
    } else {
      Alert.alert(responseJson.message);
    }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Call your API using this function. It work's for me.

Comment: It doesnt work for me because the API I need to call must use the following header : 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' , hence the problem becomes what in what form can I pass my body to the request of the fetch method. I believe the solution is close to the aproach of @AKX

Comment: try to use 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' instead of 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Tryed that aswell, the result is still the same . I think I need to pass my body in the proper form for "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Do you know how I can pass a string into valid form for this header?

Comment: Suppose you have 3 parameters the you have to pass like this --> body: "firstName=Nikhil&favColor=blue&password=easytoguess"

Answer (score 0):

finally fixed it by seting body to

```
   body: 
      `moto=${this.state.moto}`
```

it appears that urlencoded headers require parameters in the form of 
parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
return fetch(“Your URL”, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Authorization": “token”
    },
    body: "firstName=Nikhil&favColor=blue&password=easytoguess"
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function (data) {
        alert(“Success”)
        console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        alert("error occur")
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('email', 'test@gmail.com');
formData.append('password', '123456');

fetch("https://test.com/api/login", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(
(result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```